# Generating vector data (points) for OpenLayers Cluster

Tags: cluster-computing, openlayers, geojson

In my web application I am going to use `OpenLayers.Strategy.AnimatedCluster` strategy due to the fact that I need to visualize a great amount of point features. [Here](http://acuriousanimal.com/code/animatedCluster/) is a very good example of what it looks like. In both examples in above mentioned example the data (point features) are generated of taken from the `GeoJSON` file.

**So, can anybody provide me with a file containing 100 000+** (better is even 500 000+) **features (world cities, for instance), or explain how I can generate them so that they will be located all over the world** (not like in Spain in the first example in above mentioned link).

Answer (score 0):

use a geolocation database to supply you the data you need.  [GeoLite, for example](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite)

If 400K+ locations is ok, use download their [CSV CITY LIST](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity_CSV/GeoLiteCity-latest.zip)

If you want more, then you might want to give the [Nominatim downloads](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm), but they are quite bulky (more than 25GB) and parsing data is not as simple as a csv file.